# Using RCurl/httr for Github Basic Authorization

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to create an OAuth token from the command line using the [instructions here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use). I am able to use `curl` from the command line, and get the correct response

```
curl -u 'username:pwd' -d '{"scopes":["user", "gist"]}' \
  https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

Now, I want to replicate the same in R using `RCurl` or `httr`. Here is what I tried, but both commands return an error. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
httr::POST(
  'https://api.github.com/authorizations',
  authenticate('username', 'pwd'),
  body = list(scopes = list("user", "gist"))
)

RCurl::postForm(
  uri = 'https://api.github.com/authorizations',
  .opts = list(
    postFields = '{"scopes": ["user", "gist"]}',
    userpwd = 'username:pwd'
  )
)
```

Comment: in the `.opts` list, try adding `httpauth = 1L`

Comment: Try using the verbose flag to see exactly what's going on

Comment: And in `authenticate`, set `type = "basic"`

Comment: httpauth = 1L worked. Still unable to get `httr` working. @hadley, where do i add verbose in a POST command in httr.

Comment: `POST(url, c(verbose(), authenticate("user", "pass", type = "basic"))`

Comment: Nope. Still gives me an error which I have pasted [here](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/3bed4ffda01645d9be54)

Comment: The [rgithub](https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub) package might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ages old, but maybe still helpfull to some: The problem should be that the opts arguments are passed in the wrong way (lacking a curlOptions function call). The following worked for me in a different context:

```
result <- getURL(url,.opts=curlOptions(postfields=postFields))
```

(and yes, as far as I know you can use getURL function for POST requests).